# Dove e perché il neonato di ghiro viene detto cardamone?

Tags: etymology, proper-nouns, name

Cercando informazioni sul cognome Mastroianni (o meglio, cercando conferma dell'idea che Mastroianni deriva infatti da Maestro Giovanni), mi sono imbattuto su [questa pagina](https://web.archive.org/web/20160616142201/http://www.heliosmag.it/2005/giugno/cognomi.htm).

Fra i nomi che l'autore dell'articolo definisce *d'origine regionale* compare **Cardamone**.

> Molti cognomi palesano subito l’origine regionale: Addotta (nome di un pesce), Amendolea (mandorlo), Buffa (rospo), Cardamone (neonato di ghiro), Caruso (ragazzo), Garreffa (avena selvatica), Silipo (nome di una graminacea), Tallarida (pipistrello).

Naturalmente ho subito pensato al cardamomo, e invece no, a quanto pare, in qualche regione d'Italia, si dice *cardamone* per riferirsi al "neonato del ghiro".

Nell'*Ortografia moderna Italiana* di Jacopo Facciolati, un opera lessicografica del diciottesimo secolo, *cardamone* viene messo accanto a *cardamomo*, suppongo come sinonimo o variante regionale:

[image: Estratto dall'OMI di Facciolati]

> Cardamòmo , e Cardamone, frutta. *cardamomum.*

Più pertinente al problema è magari l'esistenza di un Palazzo Cardamone a Rogliano, nei pressi di Cosenza, e il fatto che molti portatori del cognome in questione siano d'origini calabresi. Ciò mi porta a pensare che la regione in questione sia la Calabria e che il "neonato di Ghiro" viene (o veniva) chiamato *cardamone* perché in effetti viene (o veniva) speziato col cardamomo, che (come spezia) è presente nel bacino mediterraneo dai tempi dei greci e dei romani.

Cosa ne pensate?

Answer (score 1):

Cardamone è un cognome calabrese e siciliano che, secondo il Rohlfs, viene dal termine dialettale 'cardamune' = neonato di ghiro'. (cfr. [link](http://www.significato.eu/cognome/Cardamone), cfr. Dizionario dei cognomi e soprannomi in Calabria del filologo tedesco Gerhard Rohlfs).